# Can someone help me in how to fix issue of disabling "eyelash/views" icon from my featured posts on my website www.startfurnishing.com?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a website www.startfurnishing.com 
A freelancer designed the website for me. Now, the problem is he is not reachable. There is a date icon and pafe view icon on every featured post of my website.

Can someone help me in how to disable "eyelash/views" icon from my featured posts on my website www.startfurnishing.com?

I checked the sourcecode and the class is "Total-views". But I don't know where to disable it in wordpress. Not sure, where to put the "Display:None" CSS code in wordpress.

Thanks!

```
<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="http://startfurnishing.com/catalogues-are-displayed-at-a-store/" rel="bookmark">Top Home furnishing eCommerce websites of India</a></h3>                                    </header>
                                    <div class="article-meta clearfix">
                                        <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><span class="screen-reader-text"> </span><span class="by">By</span><a class="url fn n" href="http://startfurnishing.com/author/admin/">admin</a></span></span><div class="posted-on post-date"><span class="author-on">on</span><span class="screen-reader-text"> </span><a href="http://startfurnishing.com/catalogues-are-displayed-at-a-store/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2019-06-25T23:09:29+00:00">June 25, 2019</time><time class="updated" datetime="2019-06-26T06:38:24+00:00">June 26, 2019</time></a></div> <div class="main-view-like">
                    <div class="total-view">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i> 59          </div>
                    </div>

                                    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this css.

.main-view-like {
    display: none;
}

.posted-on::after {
 display: none;
}
```